# Why are JavaScript primitives immutable? This seems inefficient

Tags: javascript, memory, immutability

This is not really a question per se, but I am looking for information on why JavaScript creates a new value whenever something is reassigned.

For example, a *for* loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   console.log(i);
```

I have researched that all primitives are immutable and reassigning them actually creates a new value in memory, why not overwrite the existing address?

It seems inefficient that a *for* loop running will create 100 unused locations when it completes when it could have used 1. It seems strange to me, but I am sure there is a valid reason for it?

Comment: I don't think I ever used a language where primitives were not immutable. strings, which aren't really primitive values, are usually immutable too. Many optimizations can be implement here to improve efficiency - cached values, inline implementation, etc.

Comment: *why not overwrite the existing address?* How do you know it doesn't do exactly that?

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning a primitive value to a variable overwrites the value at the address that the variable points to with a copy of the primitive value.

This loop will overwrite the value at the address that the variable **i** points to 1000 times. It will not allocate 1000 addresses in memory.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {console.log(i);}
```

What is true is that if you assign to a variable a primitive value from another variable the value will be copied and both variables would point to different locations in memory. You can check it:

```
let a = 10;
let b = a; // the value 10 from a gets copied to b
a = 20; // the value 10 gets overwritten by 20 in a
console.log(b); // prints 10
```

**Edit:**

To answer the question directly: saying that js primitive values are immutable is another way of saying that they get assigned by value as opposed to arrays and objects that get assigned by reference (or are mutable).

Whether a new memory allocation happens or not on each assignment of a primitive value to a variable is an implementation detail, but you can trust that it is done in the most efficient way by modern js engines.

Comment: Regarding the first example: you can write this loop as `for(const i = 0; i < 1000; i++) ` - it doesn't mean it's the same `i` being reassigned. Does JavaScript guarantees this behavior? how useful is it if you can't get a pointer?

Comment: The second example is pretty much how variables behave in all languages. Assigning using `=` copied the *reference*, and would behave the same with mutable values (like the arrays `[10]` and `[20]` instead `10` and `20`). A mutable change here would be `a[0] = 30` - that is - we should try the change the value we're pointing at, not the variable that's pointing at the array.

Comment: @Kobi If you write for(const i = 0; i < 1000; i++) you will get Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. Because you can not reassign a const in js. To ansver your question: a symbol i in a scope refers to the same variable no matter how often you reassign it. I do not believe it is explicitly written somewhere that js should never allocate memory on each variable reassignment. I do believe a js implementation that would do it would not be used by anyone.

Comment: @Kobi On your second comment: assignment of primitive values is done by value (a copy of a value gets assigned to a variable), but assignment of arrays is done by refference (a refference to an array gets assigned to a variable).